# Parse REST API uploading binary image data in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, rest, parse-platform

**I am getting a 500 error back when trying to send image data to the REST API**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *parseRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  [parseRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  [parseRequest setValue:@“*****” forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id:"];

  [parseRequest setValue:@“*****” forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key:"];

  [parseRequest setValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type:"];



  NSLog(@"All Headers: %@",[parseRequest allHTTPHeaderFields]);



  NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:data]];

  [parseRequest setHTTPBody:imageData];



  NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;

  NSError *theError = NULL;

  NSError *theJSONError = NULL;



  NSData *theResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:parseRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];

  NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:theResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  NSDictionary *dataDictionaryResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theResponseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&theJSONError];



  NSLog(@“Url to send request: %@“,url);

  NSLog(@“Response String: %@",responseString);

  NSLog(@"Response Error: %@",theError);
```

**This returns :**

All Headers:

```
{

    "Content-Type:" = "image/png";

    "X-Parse-Application-Id:" = *****;

    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:" = *****;


}

Url to send request: https://api.parse.com/1/files/pic2.png

Response String:  *HTML page with 500 error*

Response Error: (null)
```

I'm assuming that it doesn't like the binary data being passed as the HTTPBody but as I'm not getting any error messages back it's hard to tell what's going on. Making the same request with CURL works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *parseRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];                                   
    [parseRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [parseRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [parseRequest setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [parseRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // post body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // add params (all params are strings)

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // add image data
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
    if (imageData) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [parseRequest setHTTPBody:body];

    // set URL
    [parseRequest setURL:requestURL];
```

Comment: Tried a cut down version of this as there are no params to add, with no luck `[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  }

  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`